# How to parse angular 2 templates with pug

Tags: angularjs, pug

Trying to figure out how to keep my template parsing from blowing up.

```
.modal.fade(#childmodal='bs-modal', bsmodal='',  tabindex='-1')
```

Right now I get a parse error due to `#childmodal`  I tried `ref-childmodal` but that blows up the pug-html-loader as well.  I also added `doctype html` to the top of the file to no avail.

Any advice on what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
doctype html
.modal.fade('#childmodal'='bs-modal' 'bsmodal'=''  'tabindex'='-1')
```